vscode zsh export zshrc error on Permission denied and bad assignment
when I open zsh in vscode, it exports errors as follows:
/var/folders/5g/6zj9tk192w35xr6p5c79rmw80000gn/T/myname-code-zsh/.zshrc:37: can't create temp file for here document: permission denied 

/var/folders/5g/6zj9tk192w35xr6p5c79rmw80000gn/T/myname-code-zsh/.zshrc:40: bad assignment

According to Gpt, I create an variant, then do the assignment.
 VARNAME="$(echo ${ITEM%%=*})"   VALUE="$(echo -e ${ITEM#*=})"   eval "export $VARNAME=\"$VALUE\""
It turns out to be futile, because vscode seems to overwrite this zshrc, then exports the same error again.
Corresponding code is as follows:
# Apply EnvironmentVariableCollections if needed
if [ -n "${VSCODE_ENV_REPLACE:-}" ]; then
    IFS=':' read -rA ADDR <<< "$VSCODE_ENV_REPLACE"     # permission denied error
    for ITEM in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
        VARNAME="$(echo ${ITEM%%=*})"
            export $VARNAME="$(echo -e ${ITEM#*=})" # bad assignment
    done
    unset VSCODE_ENV_REPLACE
fi
if [ -n "${VSCODE_ENV_PREPEND:-}" ]; then
    IFS=':' read -rA ADDR <<< "$VSCODE_ENV_PREPEND"
    for ITEM in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
        VARNAME="$(echo ${ITEM%%=*})"
        export $VARNAME="$(echo -e ${ITEM#*=})${(P)VARNAME}"
    done
    unset VSCODE_ENV_PREPEND
fi
if [ -n "${VSCODE_ENV_APPEND:-}" ]; then
    IFS=':' read -rA ADDR <<< "$VSCODE_ENV_APPEND"
    for ITEM in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
        VARNAME="$(echo ${ITEM%%=*})"
        export $VARNAME="${(P)VARNAME}$(echo -e ${ITEM#*=})"
    done
    unset VSCODE_ENV_APPEND
fi


Those are complex useless echos; if you can explain what the code is supposed to accomplish, it can probably be simplified drastically.

I ran into this today, after using rye to create my venv. I found this vscode-python issue that pointed me to the solution:

Quit VSCode.

In your home directory, find the directory that looks something like this:
~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.14.1-darwin-arm64/python_files/deactivate/zsh/


chmod 0777 the file 'deactivate' in that directory.
chmod 0777 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.14.1-darwin-arm64/python_files/deactivate/zsh/deactivate


Relaunch VSCode.


The problem went away for me.
